# how to diable https and use http for browing sites using http

Tags: http, ubuntu, https, mozilla

I want to disable https and want to access a site by http (for experimental purposes).I am using firefox on ubuntu 12.4. I tried by disabling SSL in browser.But then i am not able to access sites with https.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Some sites, require using https (SSL) for accessing them. The site you try to access would probably redirect you to https (SSL), even if you decide to use http. In that case, you cannot disable the SSL use from your browser, because it is a demand from your target site.

Hope I helped...

Comment: yes that helped..Thank you. I know that gmail and facebook allows user to disable https. and it makes sense too.I think website should allow us this disabling .